# How to enable a virtual host with Apache for a website in an user directory under Debian?

Tags: apache

I want to run locally a web site, whose files are in my user directory, I made the .conf file below, a2ensite'd, apache reloaded and when I type /localhost/instanote.com in my browser, it isn't found.

```
ServerName instanote.com

ServerAlias insta-note.com




DocumentRoot /home/thomas/ownCloud/CW14/cms_cw14
<Directory "/home/thomas/ownCloud/CW14/cms_cw14">
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted

</Directory>

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

I do not know why, but openings and closing tags "<" "VirtualHost *:80 ">" " "<" "/VirtualHost" ">" at the beginning and the end are not showed above, but they are present in my code
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that is not how hosts work inside an http server, no clue where you have that idea from. If you send a request to `localhost`, then _that_ is the host. Anything appended inside the request path is considered a directory inside the path, _not_ a host name. The host you defined, "instanote.com", will only answer to requests sent to `https://instanote.com/...`. Not to any request send to `http://localhost/...`...

Comment: thanks, but I tried first https://instanote.com/ but it goes to the web to a site that has nothing to see... That's why I thought to look in virtualhost could be an idea. Now I tried with sitebidon.com ( same.conf file, with sitebidon instead of instanote), still not found

Comment: This reads like you should take a look into how name resolution in the internet works and how http requests are structured and created. You cannot simply make up a name and hope that things magically work. At least you have to configure a local name resolution instance (a DNS server) for this, how else should the browser know which of your local systems to connect to and why?

Comment: thanks for the advice